# Matlab: Calling a handle from GUI in a seperate function

Tags: matlab, user-interface, matlab-guide

I have the following edittext function:

```
function startfile_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)

function startfile_CreateFcn(hObject, eventdata, handles)
if ispc && isequal(get(hObject,'BackgroundColor'), get(0,'defaultUicontrolBackgroundColor'))
set(hObject,'BackgroundColor','white');
end
```

I also have the following push button that calls the function (images_seq):

```
function video_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
images_seq
```

I want the (images_seq) function which is within the same .m file to call the edittext function. The (images_seq) function looks like this:

```
function [ output_args ] = images_seq( output_name,images_dir,img_format, frame_rate, handles)

start_file = get(handles.startfile,'string');
```

The error I am getting is the following:

```
Not enough input arguments.
```

Please help

Comment: You have defined `images_seq` with 5 input arguments and `video_Callback` calls it with 0. As the error message quite clearly states, that's not enough input arguments.

Comment: Good point, how do I fix this?

Comment: You provide input arguments...

Comment: When I do so it states that there are (undefined functions or variables)

Comment: You'll probably want to define them before trying to pass them to another function.

Comment: they are defined within the function I am trying to run: function [ output_args ] = images_seq( output_name,images_dir,img_format, frame_rate,handles)

Comment: If they're defined in the function then you don't need to pass them as arguments. Have you copy+pasted this code from somewhere?

Comment: Thank you I predefined the variables and it worked. Yes I had this code from before and I was trying to incorporate it into a GUI.

Comment: Ignore my previous (now-deleted) comment about deleting this post: the answer below didn't load for me. Don't delete questions that have answers. Sorry!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

fisrt when you call a function you have to input their argument that function need them,in your code you have this function

```
function [ output_args ] = images_seq( output_name,images_dir,img_format,frame_rate, handles)

start_file = get(handles.startfile,'string');
```

but you call the function in wrong way for call this function you have to input all arguments

```
 function video_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
 images_seq(o_name,dir,img_f,f_rate,handles)
```

for a simple example suppose that you have a function that this function name is addd in addd.m file

```
function out=addd(x,y)
out=x+y;
```

if you enter in command window below code you get same error

```
>>addd
Error using addd (line 2)
Not enough input arguments.
```

for call this function you have to input x,y(input arguments)

```
>> addd(1,2)

ans =

     3
```